# How to add new lines inside a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to print out each key on a different line in the dictionary, but don't know how. The assignment I'm tackling doesn't allow loop statements, so printing each line individually using for loop is out of the question. Please help

So this is my code

```
students = ['Tommy', 'Kitty', 'Jessie', 'Chester', 'Curie', 'Darwing', 'Nancy', 'Sue', 
            'Peter', 'Andrew', 'Karren', 'Charles', 'Nikhil', 'Justin', 'Astha', 'Victor', 
            'Samuel', 'Olivia', 'Tony']

assignment = [2, 5, 5, 7, 1, 5, 2, 7, 5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 5, 2, 7, 2, 7]

groupset=set(assignment)    
sorted_list=sorted(list(groupset)) 
ansdict={}
ansdict={f'Group {a}':[students[b] for b in range(len(students)) if assignment[b] == a] for a in sorted_list}
print(ansdict)
```

and the output is

```
{'Group 1': ['Curie', 'Andrew', 'Karren', 'Charles', 'Justin'], 'Group 2': ['Tommy', 'Nancy', 'Nikhil', 'Victor', 'Olivia'], 'Group 5': ['Kitty', 'Jessie', 'Darwing', 'Peter', 'Astha'], 'Group 7': ['Chester', 'Sue', 'Samuel', 'Tony']}
```

when I want it to be

```
{'Group 1': ['Curie', 'Andrew', 'Karren', 'Charles', 'Justin'],
 'Group 2': ['Tommy', 'Nancy', 'Nikhil', 'Victor', 'Olivia'],
 'Group 5': ['Kitty', 'Jessie', 'Darwing', 'Peter', 'Astha'],
 'Group 7': ['Chester', 'Sue', 'Samuel', 'Tony']}
```

Comment: How about `pprint`? `from pprint import pprint;
pprint(ansdict)`

Comment: `for k,v in ansdict.items(): print(f"{k}: {v}")`

Comment: unfortunately the course doesn't allow any modules so pprint isn't allowed. Also the for k,v is a loop statement, so also not allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless one of the students is related to Little Bobby Tables, maybe just add newlines to the string representation:

```
print(str(ansdict).replace('],', '],\n'))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
prints = [print(f'{key}: {value}') for key, value in ansdict.items()]
```

Edit: Less janky alternative

```
print('\n'.join([f'{key}: {value}' for key, value in ansdict.items()]))
```

Comment: when I print it, the bottom has [None, None, None, None], do you know how to remove it?

Comment: Are you doing print(prints)? You don't need to do it. Just run the code as is, and the print statements within should execute without issue.

Comment: I've also added a less janky alternative by just joining the strings with a newline char.

Answer (score -1):

```
sorted_list=sorted(list(groupset)) 

ansdict={}
ansdict={f'Group {a}':[students[b] for b in range(len(students)) if assignment[b] == a] for a in sorted_list}

for key in ansdict.keys():
    print(key,ansdict[key])
```